# ZeroMQ Migration 32 bit to 64 bit runtime error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, migration, 32bit-64bit, zeromq

I have a Client Server project running in Visual Studio 2010 using ZeroMQ. I am able to build and run the project in 32 bit environment. While migration from 32 bit to 64 bit i am getting a Runtime error stating -

> Unhandled exception at 0x000007feed3be117 (libzmq.dll) in ClockClientTester.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow.

In the stack it is showing error in map

```
libzmq.dll!std::map<unsigned short,zmq::select_t::family_entry_t,   std::less<unsigned short>,std::allocator<std::pair<unsigned short const ,zmq::select_t::family_entry_t> > >::operator[](const unsigned short & _Keyval)  Line 210 + 0x15 bytes
```

Any suggestion would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Use the runnable code snippet for runnable code only please.

Comment: ok. Is it proper now ?

Comment: I found the solution. While using already compiled binary, it is working properly.